# How can I access short section content to avoid repetition?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I'm making frequent use of short section names for styling. I want the short names to appear in page headers and the longer name only in the document itself.

I have that worked out, but it requires a lot of repetition of information. For example:

```
\section[1--10]{1--10 Proem and summary}
...
\section[11--20]{11--20 The adventure begins}
```

Rather than repeat `1--10` (or the equivalent) each time, which is tedious and error-prone, I'm wondering if there's a way to rewrite the printout of sections in the document so that the short section name and long name are both printed.

```
% I'd like this to print "1-10 Proem and summary" in the document itself.
\section[1--10]{Proem and summary}
```

I'm attaching a minimal working example below with the other styling I've done so far.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalfont\itshape}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{Commentary: {#1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}}
\rfoot{\nouppercase{\thepage}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section[1--10]{1--10 Proem}

\lipsum

\section[11--55]{11--55 Something else}

\lipsum

\section[56--100]{56-100  Another thing}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

I suspect that [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) could do this, but I haven't been able to work out how.

Comment: It could well be easiest to create your own \section command, rather than trying to modify the defaults.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm happy to hear how to do that, but I wouldn't have any idea how to start. Pointers or suggestions of where to look welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it by redefining the section command so that

\section[55]{Title}

will create a section title of "11--55 Title" if the previous section was of the form "*--10 Some other title". There is no error checking to ensure that the new section number is bigger than the old one, although this would not be hard to do.

The second page of the MWE below looks like:

[image]

and here is the actual code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% mwe and geometry used just for MWE
\usepackage[textheight=40mm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{headings}% turn page headings on
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}% turn off section numbers

\let\realSection=\section% save the "real" section so that we can use it after we change it
\newcounter{RunningSection}% for counting our pseudo sections
\newcommand\mysection[2][\relax]{% overwriting the section command
  \refstepcounter{RunningSection}% increment running sections
  \xdef\tempSec{\arabic{RunningSection}}%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\addtocounter{RunningSection}{1}% if no default argument: X--X
  \else\setcounter{RunningSection}{#1}%
  \fi%
  \xdef\tempSec{\tempSec--\arabic{RunningSection}}%
  \realSection[\tempSec]{\tempSec\space#2}%
}
\let\section=\mysection
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{Commentary: {#1}}}% set section marks

\begin{document}

  \section[10]{Proem}
  \lipsum[1]

  \section[55]{Something else}
  \lipsum[2]

  \section{Something different}% with no optional argument increment by 1
  \lipsum[3]

  \section[100]{Another thing}
  \lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

**EDIT (using with titlesec)**

If you want to use this with `titlesec` then insert the `titlesec` commands before the new `\section` macro and then right before your bibliography put the line:

```
\let\section=\realSection
```

This makes the section command revert to its usual meaning and so all is well. In more detail:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% mwe and geometry used just for MWE

\pagestyle{headings}% turn page headings on
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}% turn off section numbers

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalfont\itshape}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{Commentary: {#1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}}
\rfoot{\nouppercase{\thepage}}

\let\realSection=\section% save the "real" section so that we can use it after we change it
\newcounter{RunningSection}% for counting our pseudo sections
\newcommand\mysection[2][\relax]{% overwriting the section command
  \refstepcounter{RunningSection}% increment running sections
  \xdef\tempSec{\arabic{RunningSection}}%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\addtocounter{RunningSection}{1}% if no default argument: X--X
  \else\setcounter{RunningSection}{#1}%
  \fi%
  \xdef\tempSec{\tempSec--\arabic{RunningSection}}%
  \realSection[\tempSec]{\tempSec\space#2}%
}
\let\section=\mysection
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{Commentary: {#1}}}% set section marks

\begin{document}

  \section[10]{Proem}
  \lipsum[1]

  \section[55]{Something else}
  \lipsum[2]

  \section{Something different}% with no optional argument increment by 1
  \lipsum[3]

  \section[100]{Another thing}
  \lipsum[4]

  \let\section=\realSection
  \begin{thebibliography}{100}
    \bibitem{AJS}
    {\sc H.~H. Andersen, J.~C. Jantzen, and W.~Soergel}, {\em Representations of
      quantum groups at a {$p$}th root of unity and of semisimple groups in
      characteristic {$p$}: independence of {$p$}}, Ast\'erisque, 1994, 321.
  \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

If you need to change from these "fancy sections" back to normal sections several times then you can use

```
\let\section=\realSection
... % normal sections
\let\section=\mysection
.... % fancy sections
\let\section=\realSection
... % normal sections
... etc
```

**EDIT II (a simplistic approach)**

Finally, the calculation is meant to make this easier on the user. As the OP doesn't like this, here is a simpler solution:

```
\let\realSection=\section
\newcommand\mysection[2][]{%
  \realSection[#1]{#1 #2}%
}
\let\section=\mysection
```

This is used as

```
 \section[1--10]{Proem}
```

and you need to write `\let\section=\realSection` before your bibliography etc.

Comment: This seems very close, but I have two issues. Most importantly, my sections are usually of the form `10--20`, not `10`. That is, they're a range, not a single number. Second, it appears that I can't use this together with `titlesec`. Is that right?

Comment: @Telemachus Here the first `\section[10]{Proem}` expands to `1--10 Proem` and the following `\section[55]{Something else}` expands to `11--55 Something else`. That is, the macro automatically takes care of the left-hand "section number". (I assumed that the left-hand number is always 1 more than the last right-hand number.) My code creates the section title you asked for. As it wasn't part of the question, I haven't tried this with `titlesec` but what I have written is compatible with the code that you have, so I don't see why it wouldn't work. Try it and let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I don't think it is compatible with my MWE from above (which does include `titlesec`). If I put your code after the inclusion of `titlesec`, the `titlesec` styling is overwritten (and I end up with an odd extra heading for 51-52 * over my bibliography). If I put the `titlesec` inclusion after your code, your changes have no effect. So they seem to conflict somehow. I appreciate the effort, but I am using `titlesec`. Rather than such a complex macro, is it possible just to compose the range in the short section with the long section wording?

Comment: Hi @Telemachus, as advertised, this macro is fully compatible with your `titlesec` commands. I have edited the post to explain. In fact, the only line relevant to your `titlesec` commands is the one beginning with `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}` which I took from your MWE. Apart from this it is only necessary to reset the section command back to the default meaning before your bibliography.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This is interesting, but I'm going to wait before accepting. I keep thinking there should be a simpler way to have `\section` simply paste the range I give it to the longer name, rather than doing all the calculating.

Comment: @Telemachus All of the "calculating" is to make life easier for you -- after all, your post motivated this by saying that your current approach was "tedious and error-prone". If you don't want this you can just remove it. See the edited post.

Comment: What was tedious and error-prone was entering the line number or range *twice*. I'm editing a classical text, and the references may become more complicated than the minimal example. I didn't want to lock myself into a solution based on an automatically incrementing counter. Your "simplistic" solution is exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you.